# How to call aws batch jobs from react UI

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, docker

I am working on a prototype in react where by I need an ability to trigger AWS Batch jobs from a button click from the UI.
The AWS Batch jobs are built on Docker images, so basically I need to call them from react UI.

I am new to react so not sure if this is possible.
Currently I have a job.json like this.

```
{
  "jobName": "tests-schedule",
  "jobQueue": "test-infra-jq-alpha",
  "jobDefinition": "uat-tests",
  "containerOverrides": {
  "environment": [
    {
      "name": "SES_FROM_ADDRESS",
      "value": "xxx@yy.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "SES_TO_ADDRESS",
      "value": "test-alerts@yy.com"
    },
    {
      "name": "SES_IDENTITY_ARN",
      "value": "arn:aws:ses:us-east-1:123456:identity/yy.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

And I am calling this from AWS CLI from command prompt.

```
aws batch submit-job --cli-input-json file://job.json --no-verify-ssl --profile 
xxxx
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoking AWS Service from a React client is possible. In fact, one way to solve this is to look at building an ***AWS Serverless application*** where you can write Lambda functions that invoke AWS Batch.

For example if you were to write Lambda functions to invoke AWS Batch from Java, you can use the Java runtime API and https://sdk.amazonaws.com/java/api/latest/software/amazon/awssdk/services/batch/BatchClient.html.

Or use other SDKS in other programming languages to write Lambda functions for AWS Batch.

Now you can then use API Gateway to handle HTTP Requests from your React client. The React Client uses the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) to send requests to API Gateway. API Gateway invokes the Lambda functions that invoke AWS Batch operations. Data is returns to the React app in a response where you can parse the data and display it.

This approach is a valid pattern. To give you an idea, look at this example:

[Create a photo asset management application that lets users manage photos using labels](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-library/latest/ug/s3_example_cross_PAM_section.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I am not a java guy. Is there a way to call this API say from a python script or something? If yes, can I call a python script on a button click event from a react component which will then execute the python AWS API?

Comment: If you look at the examples in the link - there are other SDK languages. TO answer your question, yes - you can use Python SDK to write Lambda functions to invoke AWS Batch. Then hook them up to API Gateway the same way. Then you can do React->API Gateway->Lambda functions that are implemented in Python. Hope this helps.

Comment: sorry, couldn't locate the python sdk in that sdk link. could you pls paste the link for that?

Comment: Even better - can you add a Git hub issue here. https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/issues. State you want the PAM Example in Python. Coming from a user - it will get a quicker response

Comment: Perfect - it will be picked up by my team!